# How to specify instance type in dataflow jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

We are using data flow jobs to delete the data store entries. We are using the below mentioned command.

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run del-data-8 --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Datastore_to_Datastore_Delete --parameters datastoreReadGqlQuery='select * from `ml-data`' --parameters datastoreReadProjectId=xxx --parameters datastoreDeleteProjectId=xxx
```

What parameter we should use to specify the instance type for the above data flow job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the instance type with the flag [--machine-type](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options). For more information on the machine types you can choose, you can refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#top_of_page).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Update: It's now called --worker-machine-type

Answer (score 1):

You could use workerMachineType for setting them. Please refer the below doc.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options